# Canceling my pending withdrawal BTC

Tags: cryptography, withdrawal

How can i cancel my pending withdrawal BTC of $1,240. Its been pending for 2 days. it has no confirmations and on the blockchain it says it receives 0 and sent 0. Someone PLEASE help me!

Comment: Are you withdrawing from a custodial service? If so, this is a customer service concern and you'll need to contact the service to ask for their help. If you are withdrawing from a non-custodial wallet and you have already broadcast the transaction to other nodes on the network, then there is ~no way to cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cancel the transaction, but what you can do is to spend that same UTXO to a different address of yourselves (effectively a double-spend).

The reason it has no confirmations is likely that the fee is not sufficient for miners to prioritise your transaction in their mempool. As long as it has no confirmations, you can still double-spend to an address of your choosing.

Comment: how do i double spend and how much do i have to put

Comment: You 're'-spend the same, unconfirmed UTXO to an address of yourself. At this time, if you set a fee of 110 sats/byte (https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/), then your transaction will be confirmed in the next block.